# If $f, g: \Omega \to \mathbb C$ are holomorphic and $g \not\equiv 0$, is $f/g$ meromorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, meromorphic-functions

I know that since $g$ is holomorphic, then the zeros of $g$ are isolated.

But why should $f/g$ then be holomorphic and meromorphic?

I don't understand how to continue because how would we know what happens to $f/g$ at the zeros of $g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z_0$ is a zero of $g$ of order $m$ and if $f(z_0)\neq0$, then $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$ of $\frac fg$.

And if $z_0$ is a zero of $g$ of order $m$ and zero of order $n$ of $f$, then:

- if $n<m$, $z_0$ is a pole of $\frac fg$ of order $m-n$;
- otherwise, $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $\frac fg$.

So, yes, $\frac fg$ is a meromorphic function.

Comment: If $z_0$ is a zero of $g$ and $f(z_0) \ne 0$, how do we know $z_0$ will not be an essential singularity of $f/g$?

Comment: Because g is holomorphic, its zeroes have finite order

Comment: Because if $z_0$ is a zero of order $m$ of $g$, then$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^m\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}}\neq0,$$which would not occur if $z_0$ was an essential singularity.

Comment: Because it's clear that $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)/g(z)=\infty$, which is exactly the definition of "$f/g$ has a pole at $z_0$".